# Crear un Json en Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, jsonobject, jsonarray, alamofire

Soy nuevo en Swift y estoy tratando de hacer una json para una petición en AlamoFire 5.4
y Swift 5, el json que necesito enviar es este

```
[
   {
    "KEY": "LT_APP",
    "VALUE":"[{\"P_TIPO\":\"L\",\"P_PERNR\":\"925\",\"P_PASS\":\"GAMEROS01\",\"P_CEL\":\"6143194524\",\"P_TOKEN\":\"asdfgh\"}]"
    }
]
```

En Postman se ve asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El contenido dentro de "value" es un string

Esto es lo que tengo

```
AF.request(url,
           method: .post,parameters: jsonObject, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    .authenticate(username: user, password: password)
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
            case .success(let json):
                let rtn = JSON(json)
                print(rtn["result"]["RESPONSE"][0])
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
        }
    }
```

Trate varias maneras de crear el objeto con clases y con un diccionario tengo un objeto parecido

```
let arr1 = "[[\"P_TIPO\":\"L\"],[\"P_PERNR\":\"925\"],[\"P_PASS\":\"GAMEROS01\"],[\"P_CEL\":\"6143194524\"],[\"P_TOKEN\":\"asdfgh\"]]"
let json1 = JSON(arr1)
let rest1 : [[String: String]] = [["KEY": "LT_APP"],["VALUE": "\(arr1)"]]
```

Pero al colocarlo en parametros me da el siguiente error

Cannot convert value of type '[[String : String]]' to expected argument type 'Parameters?' (aka 'Optional<Dictionary<String, Any>>')

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Cuál es el error con el código? No funciona?

Comment: El objeto que necesito enviar lo hice en postman, pero no se como debe crearse en Swift ya trate algunas maneras pero no logro hacer el equivalente a ese objeto

Comment: actualizo la pregunta

Comment: El string que debes enviar es dinámico o es exactamente ese string?

Comment: Es dinamico pero lo deje fijo para el ejemplo, los valores los remplazo con \()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como el json que tienes que armar es dinámico, debes usar una `Class` o `Struct` de tipo `Codable`:

```
struct MiStruct: Codable {
    //Variables
    var p_tipo: String
    var p_pernr: String
    var p_pass: String
    var p_cel: String
    var p_token: String
    //Inicialización
    init(p_tipo: String, p_pernr: String, p_pass: String, p_cel: String, p_token: String) {
        self.p_tipo = p_tipo
        self.p_pernr = p_pernr
        self.p_pass = p_pass
        self.p_cel = p_cel
        self.p_token = p_token
    }
}
```

Creas un objeto de tipo `MiStruct` y la llenas con valores:

```
var miStruct = [MiStruct]()
miStruct.append(MiStruct(p_tipo: "L", p_pernr: "925",p_pass: "GAMEROS01", p_cel: "6143194524", p_token: "asdfgh"))
```

Para pasar esa estructura a json usas `JSONEncoder()`:

```
do {
    //Codificas la estructura.
    let jsonEncoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(miStruct)//Este valor debes enviar por Alamofire
    //Si quieres imprimir el objeto codificado lo pasas a string.
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonEncoded, encoding: .utf8)!
    //Imprimes el json.
    print(jsonString) 
    //[{"p_token":"asdfgh","p_tipo":"L","p_cel":"6143194524","p_pass":"GAMEROS01","p_pernr":"925"}]
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Si quieres decodificar usas `JSONDecoder()`:

```
do {
    //Decodificas en base a la estructura que creaste.
    let jsonDecoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([MiStruct].self, from: jsonEncoded)
    //Imprimes el valor decodificado.
    print(jsonDecoded)
    //[MiStruct(p_tipo: "L", p_pernr: "925", p_pass: "GAMEROS01", p_cel: "6143194524", p_token: "asdfgh")]
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Wow, muchas gracias!! Esto fui muy util, estoy un poco perdido al ser nuevo en esto pero gracias por resolver mi problema